# Are const data member allowed to change outside the class?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

If a class has a const reference data member that happens to change outside the scope of such class, is this undefined behaviour?

As an example, let's consider the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  int x;
public:
  A(int x): x(x){}
  void change(int y){
    x = y;
  }
  friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const A & a){
    os << a.x;
    return os;
  }
};

class B {
  const A & a;
public:
  B(const A & a) : a(a) {}
  friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const B & b){
    os << b.a;
    return os;
  }
};

int main(){
  A a(1);
  B b(a);
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
  a.change(2);
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

My compiler was able to execute it correctly and the debugger indicated that the `x` of B::a was changed.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: `const T &` doesn't mean that it refers to a `T` that is `const`. It means it's a reference to a `T` and you aren't allowed to use that reference to change that object. It's the same thing as `const T *`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for your response! I was thinking that was the case, but since I just learned about undefined behavior, now I have a paranoia to double-check everything first! Thanks again!

Comment: Being paranoid about UB is basically the only safe stance. If you have any doubt, it's correct to find out for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not undefined behavior. The `const` reference that is a member of `B` only means that an instance of `B` may not change it via that reference. Because it is a reference, however, something else may change it -- including other members of `B` that have their own non-`const` reference to the same instance of `A`.

Compare the addition of the member `c` to your existing `B` class, and note that we are changing it successfully within `B::changeA()` via the non-`const` reference and also from `C::change()` down in `main()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
  int x;
public:
  A(int x): x(x){}
  void change(int y){
    x = y;
  }
  friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const A & a){
    os << a.x;
    return os;
  }
};

class C
{
    A& a;
public:
    C(A& a) : a{a} {}
    void change(int y) { a.change(y); }
};

class B {
  const A & a;
  C& c;
public:
  B(const A & a, C& c) : a(a), c{c} {}
  friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const B & b){
    os << b.a;
    return os;
  }
  void changeA(int y) { c.change(y); }
};

int main(){
  A a(1);
  C c(a);
  B b(a,c);

  std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';

  a.change(2);
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';

  b.changeA(3);
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';

  c.change(4);
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
}
```

See it run live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/725754611b2618d9)</kbd>, which prints:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and examples! It made it clear!

Answer (score 4):

You may not change an object using a constant reference to it but you may change the object itself if it is not constant or using a non-constant reference to the object.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = 10;

    int &rx = x;
    const int &crx = x;

    std::cout << "rx = " << rx << '\n';
    std::cout << "crx = " << crx << '\n';

    rx = 20;

    std::cout << "rx = " << rx << '\n';
    std::cout << "crx = " << crx << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
rx = 10
crx = 10
rx = 20
crx = 20
```

It is the same as using a pointer to constant data. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = 10;

    int *px = &x;
    const int *cpx = &x;

    std::cout << "*px = " << *px << '\n';
    std::cout << "*cpx = " << *cpx << '\n';

    *px = 20;

    std::cout << "*px = " << *px << '\n';
    std::cout << "*cpx = " << *cpx << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think now I understand it better!